# Does Captain Marvel only transform if the lightning strikes him?

Tags: dc, shazam

I was showing my son who Captain Marvel / Shazam was, and I noticed something in this [clip from Justice League Unlimited](https://youtu.be/lvhqWttr6aY?t=1m29s). When he's fighting Superman, he says "Shazam!", but holds Supes in front of the lightning bolt as an attack.

This isn't an uncommon tactic, from what I've seen, but I thought it was interesting that he didn't revert to Billy Batson. Instead, he only transformed when Superman turned the tables and held Captain Marvel in front of the bolt.

In the comics, is this how his power works? I know his transformations can be prevented my preventing him from speaking, but can you also just block the lightning bolt from reaching him?

Comment: So Captain Marvel could power a flux capacitor by driving at 88 mph and saying "Shazam!"?

Comment: @anaranjada Yes, but would he transform?

Comment: Hmm, what if he hugs a lightning rod in a thunderstorm? Maybe he transforms if and only if he's hit by lightning.

Comment: I wonder if he could be a lightning rod by drawing the lightning out of the clouds? Or is his lightning special?

Comment: @RikerW The lightning is magical, AFAIK, but comes from the sky.

Comment: @CreationEdge yeah, but does the magic use the surrounding electrical charge?

Comment: @RikerW Sounds like another question. I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I just assumed that since the tag didn't exist, the question hadn't been asked!